# Animate removal of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quite simply I have this https://jsfiddle.net/8ffvtcta/ and I would like it so when one of the `div` elements are deleted then the other `div`s move animate upwards rather then move from one position to another.

How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you find it difficult to put your code in the question itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `.slideToggle()`

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).css('position', 'relative');
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).animate({left: '-=' + $(document).width() }, 150);
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).slideToggle(150, function() { $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).remove(); });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8ffvtcta/3/

Comment: Just missed. I should have given `slideUp` instead! LoL. Enjoy!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

@DinoMyte has the correct answer. But, it looks like you were originally trying to fade it out. You can achieve that by adding the opacity to your animate object:

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).css('position', 'relative');
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).animate({
        left: '-=' + $(document).width(), 
        opacity:0 
    }, 150);
    $( $(this).attr('to-delete') ).slideToggle(150);
});
```